# how to put a validation on html php code

Tags: php, html

My question is about validation in html. At the moment, if I input 100 or 1000 it will work as intended.

This is my html code:

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row" colspan = "1"><font size="5">Number of Guests:</th>
    <td colspan = "2"><input type = "text" name = "guest" maxlength = "4" id="guest" 
    pattern="[0-9]{3,4}" title = "Number of guests must be more than 100 people."></td>
</tr>
```

My problem is that when I try to input 001 or 000 it still works. How can I counter that problem? Do I have to validate in php? Thank you for any comments or suggestions.

Comment: Please Clarify what exactly do you want?

Comment: your saying value form 100 to 1000? is that then `<input type = "number" name = "guest" min = "100" max="1000" id="guest" 
 title = "Number of guests must be more than 100 people.">`

Comment: i want only value from 100-1000, i want the validation to reject if i input 001 or 000 or any starting with 0

Comment: if you want to remove arrows at right side of `input` type field use this CSS
`input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}`

Comment: In order to answer also at the second part of your question, YES, you should validate input from user server-side anyway because HTML5 input pattern attribute and input type=number do not present the same behavior in all browsers: pls see [caniuse.com pattern](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern) and [caniuse.com number](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number)

Comment: thanks for the opinion and answer all...it help me..thanks (y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This it will work for numbers

```
<input type = "number" name = "guest" min = "100" max="1000" id="guest" title = "Number of guests must be more than 100 people.">
```

Comment: +1 It's enjoyable when it doesn't require a regex to work. One should almost never use a regex unless it's the only viable solution as it contributes to make the code harder to understand.

P.S.: I'd also answer his subquestion about php, it's quite straightforward IMO, the OP is probably just unaware of "server-side first" rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1):

Using Kóta Péter idea

```
pattern="^[1-9][0-9]{2,3}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:
`^(0?[1-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]{3})$`

this way you disallow input `0100,001,099,0099`

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to get you desired value only.

```
   <input type = "text" name = "guest" maxlength = "4" id="guest" min="100" max="1000" pattern="^[1-9][0-9]*$" title = "Number of guests must be more than 100 people.">
```